# Two Table Join Index Optimization

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have the following tables:

```
items (item_id (PRIMARY), item_name)
activity (activity_id (PRIMARY), item_id (INT), user_id (INT), lat (FLOAT), lng (FLOAT), created_at)
```

I'd like to do the following query:

```
SELECT
  i.item_id,
  i.item_name,
  count(distint a.user_id) as total_count
FROM activity as a
  INNER JOIN item as i
    on a.item_id = i.item_id
WHERE (a.lat BETWEEN XXXXXXX
       and XXXXXXX
       and a.lng BETWEEN XXXXXXX
       and XXXXXXX)
    and created_at >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY)
GROUP by a.bid
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 5
```

This is a heavy query on a 3-5 million record table, even though I have the index on activity:

```
item_index (item_id, lat, lng, created_at)
```

This doesn't get used in the EXPLAIN, it just defaults to "item_id". I guess what I'm asking is - what indexes need to be added to make this query run fast or is there an optimization I can make?

Answer (score 0):

Try a derieved subquery like this

```
SELECT
  i.item_id,
  i.item_name,
  count(distint a.user_id) as total_count
FROM activity as a
  INNER JOIN (select
        item_id,
        item_name
          from item
          where a.lat BETWEEN XXXXXXX
          and XXXXXXX
          and a.lng BETWEEN XXXXXXX
          and XXXXXXX) as i
    on a.item_id = i.item_id
WHERE created_at >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY)
GROUP by a.bid
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

The index could be used for either the `where` clause, the `on` clause, or both.

In a `where` clause, an index on columns A, B, and C (in that order), can be used in the following circumstances:

- Equality on A eg (`A = a`)
- Ordered comparison on A (eg `A < a` or `A > a`)
- Equality on A and B (eg `A = a and B = b`)
- Equality on A, ordered comparison on B (eg `A = a and B < b`)
- Equality on A and B and C
- Equality on A and B and ordered comparison on C

Your `where` clause has equality and then two ordered comparisons.  I would suggest changing the `a.lng` from a `between` to an `in` and to change the index to `item_index (item_id, lng, lat, created_at)`.

You should also remove the index on `item_index(item_id)` since it is not needed.  This new index can be used anywhere that one can be.

Because of the `order by rand()`, this query has to generate the entire result set before returning any rows.  The only way to really improve the performance is by hoping that the `where` conditions are highly selective, so they reduce the size of the generated set.

You may be better off if you can structure the query to take 5 rows from `activity` or `item` and then do the joins.

Comment: I wasn't aware you could change BETWEEN to IN? Also where are you getting user_name?

Comment: The change of `between` to `in` was just a guess.  `a.lng` seemed like "language" which seems discrete, but could be something else.  `user_name` is my mistake . . . I misread `item_name`.